# Can I just download Laravel source code and upload to my ftp server ?

Tags: php, bash, laravel, ftp, vps

I wanted to install laravel 5.4 to my web server, however, the server told me there is not enough memory to allocate in order to install laravel. I am going to download the source code and paste it in my file directory without using composer in my linux server
I tried

```
$free -m
```

and return

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         23922      23348        573       2993       2899      13761
-/+ buffers/cache:       6687      17234
Swap:         7999       1033       6966
```

Is it normal ?

P.S. I don't want to buy VPS.

Thanks

Comment: You can, but if your server doesn't have enough RAM to *install* Laravel, it may struggle to *run* it too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes can, you can download from your local and upload all laravel directory and file to your server.